# yii eauth get access token

Tags: php, yii

I am using [yii-eauth](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth) in my Yii project.

I am done with the login part. However, I faced a difficulty which is: Should I get the access token so that I can do extra things like post/share to facebook? There is a facebook-php-sdk, but I believe that this yii-eauth already has the functionality to get the access token.

I tried the below code, but it returned an error saying `FacebookOAuthService and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getAccessToken".`

```
$objFB=new FacebookOAuthService();
echo $token_code=$objFB->getAccessToken("my_apps_client_id");
```

I am still new in yii-eauth. I hope someone may help me. Thanks.

Comment: try to look at `$obj` is having something  or is still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected function saveAccessToken($token) 
{
    $this->setState('auth_token', $token['access_token']);
    $this->setState('expires', isset($token['expires']) ? time() + (int)$token['expires'] - 60 : 0);
    $this->access_token = $token['access_token'];
    Yii::app()->user->setState('access_token',$this->access_token); //set this into user session

}
```

So later just have to call `Yii::app()->user->access_token` to get the access token.